# Recuperar array generado en JSON y enviado por POST

Tags: php, json, array

Creo un `array` con `JSON` y lo envio en una variable encriptada en `base64` en un formulario.
La recupero por `POST`, la desencripto y queda:

```
[
 {"idcliente":"1",
  "id_comercial":"999999",
  "preciototal":"698.01",
  "payTotalTotal":"713.01"
 }
]
```

¿Como puedo obtener cada elemento del `array` aparte para poder almacenarlo en una columna en `mysql` cada uno?
Gracias

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

para obtener del post

```
$dataJson = $_POST['datos']
```

Puedes usar `json_decode(datos)` obtendrás un array associativo con la estructura de tu json.

```
$arrayDatos = json_decode($dataJson)
```

**Ejemplo:**

```
$datosJson = <<<EOF

[
 {"idcliente":"1",
  "id_comercial":"999999",
  "preciototal":"698.01",
  "payTotalTotal":"713.01"
 }
]

EOF;

$arrayJson = json_decode($datosJson);

print_r($arrayJson);
```

Para recorrer el array por cada nodo

```
foreach ($arrayJson[0] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' = ' . $value . '<br />';  
}
```

**Resultado**

```
idcliente = 1
id_comercial = 999999
preciototal = 698.01
payTotalTotal = 713.01
```

Comment: Me devuelve "Array", no sería lo suyo un foreach o similar?

Comment: el array lo puedes recorrer con un for, foreach etc..

Comment: Y si se quiere leer solo un dato? Ej. el  id_comercial

Comment: @JuanCarlos el compañero John tiene un ejemplo de como obtener un solo valor

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$datosJson = <<<EOF
[
 {"idcliente":"1",
  "id_comercial":"999999",
  "preciototal":"698.01",
  "payTotalTotal":"713.01"
 }
]
EOF;

$arrayJson = json_decode($datosJson);

// Asi imprimirias o cojerias el valor del id_comercial
$id_comercial =  $arrayJson[0]->id_comercial;
echo $id_comercial;
?>
```